# How do I prevent Xcode 9 from moving files when I rename project folders?

Tags: xcode, project-management

When I use the Xcode 9 navigator to rename a folder, the folder changes in the hierarchy tree and Xcode also moves the directory on the filesystem. In some previous version of Xcode one could rename the project folder without the filesystem folder being affected.

How can I restore the old behaviour to rename a project folder without the filesystem hierarchy being modified?

Answer (score 0):

I just know some basics as I work on Xamarin apps, Xcode 9 synchronises the folder and the project hierarchy automatically. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006482/how-to-rename-the-folder-name-in-xcode-project-with-out-corrupting-the-files) answer for more details.